# Maintaining/updating sets of associations

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Suppose we have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE meetings (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    # other fields
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE participants (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    # other fields
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE meetings_participations (
    meeting INT,      # for joining on meetings.id
    participant INT,  # for joining on participants.id
    PRIMARY KEY(meeting,participant)
);
```

Given a particular `$meeting_id` and an array `$participant_ids` of participants in that meeting, what is a good way to update the table `meetings_participations`?

I've considered

```
DELETE FROM meetings_participations
    WHERE meeting = $meeting_id;
INSERT INTO meetings_participations
        (meeting, participant)
    VALUES
        $participations;
```

where, in PHP

```
$participations = join(',', array_map(function($p){
    return "($meeting_id,$p)";
}, $participant_ids));
```

but I wonder whether it wouldn't be better to try to conserve existing records (rather than deleting unconditionally and re-inserting). Is there a better approach to the general problem?

Comment: You can use exists clause in order to avoid "delete and then insert" logic.create two function instead of one. First function will check the existence of meeting and participant, if it doesn't match, then function returns 1 , calls another function which will insert the record. if data matches, return 0 means no need to call second function. I am mysql expert , not php. Let me know if you need help related to query.

Comment: @karanarora Thanks. Would it be better than to "delete and insert", you think? (I would generally expect 90% of them to pre-exist.)

Comment: I prefer to check existence of a record , and insert if it doesn't exists . The only reason is that delete is an expensive query. It creates logs for each row deletion and its time consuming too if records are in millions.

Comment: @karanarora Is delete more expensive than checking for existence and then updating/inserting?